# elasticsearch query with field username:a stopped working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a CouchDB document with field `username`. The query below works for all values except for "a". This strange because it used to work. I deleted my index and tried again but makes no difference. I do not see any errors either. I'm using CouchDB 1.2.1 with River plugin.

Works: `curl http://localhost:9200/profiles/_search?q=username:b`

Does not work: `curl http://localhost:9200/profiles/_search?q=username:a`

Comment: Are you sure there are values that start with "a"?  How do you have the username field analyzed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. I'm using Futon interface to verify and update documents.

Comment: BTW, this behavior is true for all other fields too. So if `firstname` has "a" as value, no results are returned.

Comment: We are going to need more information to help out.  Can you post your mappings so we can see how the type is analyzed?  Or are you using the default mapping?  Can you confirm that the documents are actually inside ES (using a tool like Head or a match_all query) and not getting stuck somewhere between ES <=> Couch?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I've posted my index and results of all query here http://pastebin.com/BerCjvCf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were using some mapping before that you are not using anymore? 
I guess now you are using the default mapping, where the word 'a' is a stopword. Thus the word 'a' does not get indexed at all. You might want to configure the username field as not_analyzed in your mapping, since I guess you want to index it as it is, without tokenizing nor anything else.

Comment: I've always used default mapping, the one mentioned on pastebin. I'll dig deeper with mapping and see how that works out. Thanks.

Comment: I think I might have never used any of the default stopwords as username! I'm quite new to elasticsearch and wan't aware of these stopwords. Thanks.